# SAS: Reading Logical Operators

Tags: sas

what does this SAS code mean?

```
1. %if (&variable ne ) then statement here
2. %if (%variable1 eq ) or (%variable2 ne ) then statement here
```

I am expecting a variable or value after the operator NE or EQ. But these codes don't have it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mix of macro and data step logic from within a macro definition.

```
%if (&variable ne ) then statement here
```

This would make more sense if it was written as

```
%if (&variable ne ) %then statement here
```

This tests whether the macro variable `&variable` is empty and skips the `statement here` if it is.

The second one is executing a macro called `%variable1` and skipping `statement here` if the macro resolves to an empty value. Exactly what happens depends on how the macro is defined. e.g. you could define it as:

```
%macro variable;
 text here
%mend;
```

which would cause `statement here` to trigger as it would be testing whether `(text here ne )`, which resolves to true.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I will check the code again.